# How to get List of objects, which contain List using hql query in java?

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

I have faced to problem. I have two tables t1 and t2. And they connected with foreign key(more exactly t1 has field id and  t2 table has id_t1_fkey field).  One record in t1 can have one or more records in t2. So I want to put all of it in list of object using dto constructor. And as a result I wish to get such kind of result:
And object number i in list:
Object_i: field1_t1, field2_t2, fieldn_t1, List[field1_t2]
                Ivanov    Ivan   [order1,order2, order3]

Now hql returns only objects such kind:

Ivanov    Ivan   order1
Ivanov    Ivan   order2
Ivanov    Ivan   order3

So you can see three useless copies Ivanov Ivan((( I don't want to send frontend a lot of copies
I have tried to write this:

t1 is table SettingsFee,which was connected @OneToMany with t2 
 t2 is "table" s.salesPartner,

//t1 Model

```
@Entity
@Table (name="t1")
@Audited
public class SettingsFee {

    public static enum Status {
        ACTIVE,
        CLOSED,
        DELETE
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private String id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;
    @Column(name="lastname")
    private String lastname;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "settingsFee")
    private List<SettingsFeeSalesPartner> salesPartner; 
    //there getters and setters
}
```

//t2 Model

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "t2")
@Audited
public class SettingsFeeSalesPartner {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "settingsfee")
    private SettingsFee settingsFee;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "salespartner")
    private Company salesPartner;//Company is another model for another table
//there getters and setters
}   

@Repository
public class SettingsFeeCustomRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    public List<SettingsFeeDTO> loadData() {
```

//there I try to choose that id which satisfy a query using filters, 
//number of results etc, but there they were deleted for simplicity.

```
    String hql = "SELECT  DISTINCT(s.id) FROM SettingsFee s INNER JOIN s.salesPartner psp WHERE s.status != 'DELETE' ";

    Query PreQuery = em.createQuery(hql)
```

//there I try to take a result list with necessary fields:

```
String hql1 = "SELECT sf.id, sf.name sf.lastname, sfp.salesPartner.id,, sfp.salesPartner.name  "
                    + "  FROM SettingsFee sf "
                    + "JOIN sf.salesPartner sfp "
                    + "WHERE sf.id IN ( :PreQuery ) "
                    + "ORDER BY sf.id";
            Query query = em.createQuery(hql1);
            List<String> preresult = PreQuery.getResultList();
            if (preresult.isEmpty()) {
                query.setParameter("PreQuery", "_");
            } else {
                query.setParameter("PreQuery", preresult);
            }
```

//there I make an Array to List

```
    List<SettingsFeeLiteHQLDTO>list= ((List<Object[]>) query.getResultList()).stream()
            .map(row -> new SettingsFeeLiteHQLDTO((String) row[0], (String) row[1], (String) row[2], (String) row[3]))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

//there I pack my list to "a list with list": 
//if id is equal, it will be replace in list.

```
List<SettingsFeeDTO> FinList= new ArrayList<SettingsFeeDTO>();
            List<String> spName=new ArrayList<String>();

            int NumList=list.size();
            for (int i=0;i<NumList;i++){
                spName.add(list.get(i).getClientName() );
                spId.add(list.get(i).getClientId());
```

//there equals was Overrided and two objects are equal if their id identical

```
if ((i!=NumList-1)&&list.get(i).equals(list.get(i+1))){
                    //do nothing
                }else if((i!=NumList-1)&&(list.get(i).equals(list.get(i+1))==false)){   //if two nabes are different
//there is special constructor          
                    FinList.add(new SettingsFeeDTO(list.get(i),spId,spName));               
                    spName=new ArrayList<String>();
                    spId=new ArrayList<String>();
                }
                else{//for last element
                    FinList.add(new SettingsFeeDTO(list.get(i),spId,spName));
                }
            }
            return FinList;
        }
```

How to overcome??? Is there any variants to minimize the amount of code?
P.S. I use Eclipse, spring framework, data:pgAdmin(postgre)

Comment: Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: please update the question with this query.